# Prevent deletion for specific id

Tags: c#, mysql, triggers, myisam, bindingsource

For ex I have a table1 with id and name field. I use bindingsource to bind data to datagridview. Now I expect that user can not delete row which table1.id = 1 or table1.id = 2.

How to do that either use C# code or trigger in MYSQL.

ps : I use save button on the bindingnavigator to update data. It's generated after I drag a dataset to winsform.

Thank in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a trigger - some general pointers:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

EDIT - as per comments:

see http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to cancel delete and raise exception to C# in trigger

Answer (score 0):

Put a `"where"` Condition while deleting that

```
Delete from table1 where table1.id != 1 OR table1.id != 2
```

Comment: No, not exactly in that. Any how you have to write one query to delete the rows right, include the where condition at that place.

Comment: I drag a dataset to form then it generates a datagridview and bindingsource, bindingnavigator, ect ... Then will save button on the bindingnavigator

Comment: I dint get what you are saying.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I meant I use a "save button" on the bindingnavigator to update data. It's generated after I drag a dataset to winsform.

Comment: I am not asking about either "save button" or some other else. Just write the code like I have shown in the row deleting region.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3880/discussion-between-kalyan-and-sun)